# High memory and disk usage

Tags: hard-drive, memory, external-hard-drive, ramdisk, memory-limit

[S.M.A.R.T. values and task manager after a game of warzone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uay9y.png)I have a problem with my memory and disk usage.I have tried fixing it many times but without result. Its an MSI GL73 8RC with:
WINDOWS 10, I dont know what version.
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H 2.20 GHz
GPU: NVIDIA Geforce RTX 1050
RAM: 8GB
2 hard disks: one SSD with 128GB and another one HDD with 1TB.
All of my games are installed on- and using - biggest disk (HDD 1TB).
When idle (doing nothing) my memory usage is about 35-40%, when playing games this can go up to around 70-90%, is this normal? When playing games this can go up to around 70-90%. Then when im playing a big game like GTA my disk usage stays at 100% for most of the time wich causes framedrops (I think). And when I play a smaller game such as FIFA 20 it also happens but less frequent. Can somebody help me with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's totally normal to have high disk/ram/cpu usage while gaming. If the game will not utilize these resources then how will it run?

Comment: bear in mind that GTA is a very large (virtual) city and streaming from disk is quite normal. One thing you might try is to whitelist or add an exception for the game's data folder to your antivirus. If it resolves some of your issue with hitching, then you can decide if you want to leave the exception enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds exactly normal, but you **might** have a hard disk issue.

High memory is not a concern as the OS will often use free memory as a cache to optimise read performance. (It can give it back when asked).

Your performance issues sound disk related. You have put your data on a large, slow disk, so reading it is going to be slow and can bottleneck your PC. You may be able to get a small speed increase by (a) deleting unused large files and (b) defragmenting your disk.  This will do 2 things - it will prefer the outer parts of your disk which are faster to read/write and they will reorder the disk to make reads of large blocks of data more efficient.  A better solution, if you have the money, is to replace HDD with ssd, which will massively improve disk performance. Depending on your metric, 10 to 100 times better disk performance is typical.

Its also worth getting a utility to check the s.M.A.R.T values on your hard drive. It is possible your disk is starting to fail, as very slow IO is a very common sign of a disk that's failing. If this us the case, back up immediately.

Comment: I have already deleted some unused files, but if I redownload a game on my first and smaller storage SSD will the performance be better then?

Comment: Yes, for that game. (Note that just deleting files won't help much above, the defrag is important).   You may also want to check that your paging file is on the SSD.

Comment: How do you check and change that because I think my paging file is on the HDD

Comment: I downloaded a S.M.A.R.T utility but I don't know where the IO is displayed.

Comment: SMART does not show IO. It reflects what the disk thinks of itself and is useful in diagnosing a failing disk (which could present as a disk with slow IO)

Comment: I played a game of cod Warzone while the S.M.A.R.T was opened. The maximum latency was 800ms so not very good and my disk usage was almost all the time at 100%. I have a picture of it and task manager. Can i send it to you?

Comment: You can upload the image and that may confirm. Smart does not work the way you Invision - it only reads what the drive thinks at a point in time.

Comment: I added the image to my question. It's after a game of warzone, a game I used to run without much problems.

Comment: The image I was looking for was the SMART result. Nevertheless, the solution is to augment your SSD capacity and reduce your reliance on HDD as this is a major bottleneck,  (SSD has become a lot cheapest. I'd probably just replace the HDD with an SSD.)

Comment: Oh I see now. Other question, do you know anything about ethernet or not?

Comment: Not sure his that's relevant here. If you have a question about Ethernet, ask another question. (As I built an ISP many years ago, and as a system/network admin for a small SaaS company I know more then many and know that there is a lot more to learn. Standard Dunning Kruger I expect)

Comment: I already asked the question. Can you take a look at it please?

Comment: Just had a look. I've nothing to add to Daniels answer which I agree with. Power line adapters do not give anything close to rated speed and there performance varies wildly per environment - it is extremely likely that is your bottleneck.   Of-course, I am assuming your internet connection is really gigabit as well.

Comment: But on the site where I bought it, it says download speeds up to 1000Mbps and my router sends 1000Mbps as well. Also in the added picture of that question, wich shows my connection specifications, it says sending and recieving 1000/1000 (Mbps).

Answer (score 0):

When memory is at 100%, your system will begin to use much slower virtual memory (stored inside your hard disks somewhere). This can lead to the system being slower. That said, your virtual memory should be running on your SSD (if you're running Windows on SSD; then virtual memory is probably on SSD as well, if you haven't changed those settings yourself).

Memory usage of 35% on idle (2.8GB) is a bit high for idle - I would suggest closing background programs that might be running, and services that you don't need, to free up some of the memory that's being used.

All that said, there's nothing *really* wrong with your system using 90-100% of memory, and keep in mind that 8GB is becoming a low amount of RAM these days. If buying another 4GB or 8GB or RAM is not an option, consider disabling some programs/services, like mentioned.

There's also nothing *really* wrong with the disk being used at 100%. This is to be expected of older HDDs - you might want to consider buying an SSD for playing games, or you can try this:

Format the HDD and choose a bigger allocation unit size (default is 4kB - increasing it to 32kB or 64kB should give you a boost for reading big files, such as game & media files. The downside is that your files will now need more space on the disk).
The least you can do with your HDD for improving performance is defragging it, though.

Comment: Can you tell my how I choose a bigger allocation unit size? The storage space won't be a problem since it's a 1TB storage disk.

Comment: Also I have most background programs closed and no other tabs opened.

Comment: You'll have to right-click on your disk and choose to format it. You'll then be able to set the allocation unit size from a drop-down menu.
If you have no background programs, services might be the issue for memory usage at idle. Although you might be only able to free 300-500MB of memory with disabling services.

Comment: If I format my disk it says all my files will be lost. So then I have to redownload all my games. Is this preventable?

Comment: You can copy the files to another location (like an external hard drive). Other than this (apart from using some paid programs which might be able to do the job without losing data), there's not much else you can do.

Comment: I think ill just have to redwonload them because my other hard drive is to small and I dont have an external hard drive. But thanks for the information, ill do that then

Comment: I reseted my whole computer because I wasn't able to format it, now I have dont it but I need to wait until my games are downloaded to see if it helped. I changed it to 64kB.